# Clear the EditText on restart of application

Tags: android, browser, android-edittext

I've created a simple browser app in android in that i've taken an EditText and an ImageButton ,and a webView,user enters url in EditText and when clicks on Imagebutton he will go to entered URL's webpage.all working well but i just want is that when user again start the application the last entered text should be cleared..Thanking you my code is as below:

MainACtivity.java

```
package com.example.findmap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.BoringLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MapActivity extends Activity {
WebView browser;
EditText et;
ImageButton ib;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        browser =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et.setText(" ");
        ib =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 String url = et.getText().toString();
                  //  browser.loadUrl("http://www.gmail.com");
                    browser.loadUrl("http://"+url);
                     browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                     browser.clearCache(true);

            }
        });

         }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_map, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add this code in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {


    super.onResume();

    et.setText("");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call `onResume()` for that. And in your onResume() you should right `et.setText("");`
I hope it will help you.

Comment: @jimmy cool Please let me know whether this works for you or not.

Comment: @Rahil-Tnx bro...hav nyc day!